# ASP.NET MVC: Validation Error on Model Update (foreign key field)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

My Model `PaymentRequest` is as below:

```
 public class PaymentRequest
 {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        .....
        .....
        [DefaultValue(PaymentStatus.WaitForPayment)]
        public PaymentStatus Status { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public virtual ApplicationUser RequestedBy { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RequestedBy")]
        public string RequestedById { get; set; }


    }
```

Here `RequestedById` is Foreign key. When I'm goint to update `Status` field of my Model, like below:

```
    PaymentRequest paymentrequest = db.PaymentRequests.Find(id);

    if (paymentrequest == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    db.Entry(paymentrequest).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    paymentrequest.Status = PaymentRequest.PaymentStatus.WaitForPayment;
    db.SaveChanges();
```

I face validation error about Required property of `RequestedBy` altough it is present when I check in debug mode. But when I manually set ID field as below, problem resolve:

```
PaymentRequest paymentrequest = db.PaymentRequests.Find(id);
if (paymentrequest == null || paymentrequest.PaymentType != PaymentRequest.PaymentRequestType.Tankhah)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}

db.Entry(paymentrequest).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
paymentrequest.Status = PaymentRequest.PaymentStatus.WaitForPayment;
string uid = paymentrequest.RequestedById;// <-- fix lines
paymentrequest.RequestedById = uid;// <-- fix lines
db.SaveChanges();
```

I want to know what's wrong that lead to validation error? Is it about `virtual` property and its lazy load behavior or I missed something else?

Comment: You don't add the `[Required]` to the complex object, you add it to the `RequestedById` property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It fixed the things.